# C++: How do I pass a derived object into a class that holds its abstract base?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class which I want to hold an abstract class object.

```
class myClass
{
abstractClass abstractObject; //won't work since abstractClass is abstract
// ....
}
```

where `abstractClass` is an abstract base class. Then I might have a non-abstract `derivedClass1` and `derivedClass2`, both of which inherit from `abstractClass`. I want to pass these derived class into `myClass`. How do I do this using rvalues?

I want to be able to e.g. say

```
myClass someOBJ(derivedClass1(x, y, z));
myClass someOtherOBJ(derivedClass2(x,y,z));
```

and then these two objects now hold objects of type `derivedClass1` and `derivedClass2`.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you trying to write constructors of myClass that accept objects of these derived classes?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to have to create the objects outside the class and then pass them in. I want to create them simultaneously like an rvalue.

Comment: You should use the pointer of the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use a pointer pointing to the object like `abstractClass* ptr;` and write a constructor accepting rvalues like `myclass::myclass(abstractClass&& rval)`

Comment: Will check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain polymorphism, you will need to use either a pointer or a reference to `abstractClass` in `myClass`.

The proper C++ was to accomplish this is by using `std::unique_ptr<>`:

```
#include <memory>

class AbstractClass
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};


class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass
{
public:
    void func() {};
};


class myClass
{
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass> ptr;

public:
    myClass(AbstractClass* p) : ptr(p) {}
};


int main()
{
    myClass(new DerivedClass());

    return 0;

    //myClass will automatically call delete on the pointer
}
```